# Showing facebook tab inside facebook ONLY

Tags: php, html, css, facebook

**Hi Guys** 
I'm using woobox to create facebook tabs for my pages - and ive got a question :
I've got an HTML Page (placed on my own server), using it as for my facebook tab (used woobox to create the tab), now, is there's a way when someone go by the full URL 
(http://www.spawnedchaos.com/hammercult12/fbTabs/fbCount.html in this case) 
he will be redirected automatically to the facebook tab (showing the page inside facebook) ?

please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved with small JavaScript snippet in your page:

```
// replace next URL with one for your page
if (window.top === window)
  window.top.location = '//facebook.com/pages/-/SomePageID?sk=app_12345678';
```

This isn't blocking the page from being displayed but the redirection will happen as long as this code is executed so probably the sooner it'll appear in the page the better.

Beware that this is just checking that the parent window is the same as current so generally it means that page running not in frame, and not really check for Facebook specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use a server-side script of some kind (ie, PHP) instead of using just a flat HTML file, then you can check for the presence of the signed request that Facebook posts to the tabs. That's the only 100% sure-proof way to ensure that the content can only be opened via the Facebook tab.

JuicyScripter's solution will work in most cases, but it could be circumvented if someone were to open your page's URL in an iframe.

If front-end javascript is your only option, a better test may be to check the referring URL and make sure it's coming from your page. IE:

```
    if (document.referrer.indexOf('facebook.com/pages/-/SomePageID') == -1) {
      window.top.location = '//facebook.com/pages/-/SomePageID?sk=app_12345678';
    }
```